# Converse of existing question on L^p convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

My question is about this:

[Convergence in $L^p$ of $f_n$ implies convergence in $L^1$ of $|f_n|^p$ and $f_n^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126278/convergence-in-lp-of-f-n-implies-convergence-in-l1-of-f-np-and-f-n)

It was shown that the author's question was indeed true by the use of MVT.

Is the converse also true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the converse is not true.

**Example** Let

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases} -1 & x \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2} \right] \\ 1 & x \in \bigg(\frac{1}{2},1\bigg]. \end{cases}$$

Then

$$\int_0^1 ||f_n(x)|-1| \, dx = 0$$

i.e. $|f_n| \to 1$ in $L^1([0,1])$. On the other hand, $$\int_0^1 |f_n(x)-1| \, dx = 2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}1 \, dx = 1.$$ This means that $f_n \not \to 1$ in $L^1([0,1])$.

Similary, one can show that $f_n^2 \to 1$ in $L^1([0,1])$ but, again, $f_n$ does not converge to $1$ in $L^2([0,1])$.