# Sequence in $L^p(X,M,\mu)$

Tags: measure-theory

I have two question.

Suppose that {$f_k$} is a sequence in $L^p(X,M,\mu)$ such that
$f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x)$
exists for $\mu$ -a.e. $x \in X$.
Assume $1\le p<\infty$,
$\liminf_{k\to \infty} ||f_k||_p = a$
is finite.

- First one is proving that $f \in L^p$ and $||f||_p \le a$.

And if additionally assume that $||f||_p = \lim_{k \to \infty} ||f_k||_p $.

- Second one is to prove $$\lim_{k \to \infty} ||f-f_k||_p =0 $$

Those are very natural fact, but I want have strict proof of them. How can I approach?

Comment: For the second question, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/pointwise-and-convergence-of-lp-norms-implying-convergence-in-lp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) is easy using Fatou's lemma

Comment: Yeah. It's directly come from Fatou's lemma. thanks.