# Do weak convergence and convergence of norms imply convergence in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $(f_n)_n\subseteq L^2(0,1)$ s.t. 
>   $$
> f_n \rightharpoonup f, \qquad\qquad \Vert f_n\Vert_2 \to \Vert f\Vert_2
> $$
>   where $\rightharpoonup$ means *weak convergence*. Is it true that $f_n \to f$ *strongly*, i.e. in $L^2$?

I don't know how to start and I really would like some hints on how to solve it. Actually, I do not know: is it true? I don't manage to find any counterexample...

Is this somehow related to the well-known fact that **a.e. convergence** + **convergence of norms** in $L^p$ do imply **convergence in $L^p$** (*Rudin*, R&CA, ex. 17 pag. 73)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you state more precisely what the "well-known fact" means? We don't all have access to Rudin's books. What does "a.e. convergence + convergence of norms in $L^p$ do imply convergence in  L" mean?

Comment: I guess I was referring to something of this kind https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp (i.e., quite verbatim, if you have a sequence of functions that 1. converges pointwise a.e. and 2.their p-norm make up a convergent sequence (of real numbers), then the sequence converges strongly in $L^p$).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's almost surely a duplicate, but I think answering is shorter than finding the corresponding one.

**Hint:** we have $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_{L^2}^2=\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}^2-2\langle f,f_n\rangle+\lVert f_n\rVert_{L^2}^2$. The second term converges to $2\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}^2$.

Comment: Simply beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: Please, does the boundedness of the domain play a role?

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso : no, here $L^2(0,1)$ could be replaced by any Hilbert space.

Answer (score 12):

In every Uniformly Convex Banach space this is true. See for example the book of Brezis Proposition 3.32 page 78: Brezis, Haim Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations. Universitext. Springer, New York, 2011. xiv+599 pp

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestion, it's very interesting.

Comment: @Tomás Super useful. Thank you!