# sequence of functions in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convergence a.e. and of norms implies that in Lebesgue space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-lebesgue-space)

Let $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ be a sequence of functions in $L^p$ ($1 \leq p < \infty)$ that converge almost everywhere to a function $f$ in $L^p$.

What's the shortest proof showing that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$ if and only if $||f_n ||\rightarrow ||f||$?

Comment: Do you have a long proof you are trying to shorten?  Are both directions too long?

Comment: In particular, proving convergence in $L^p$ is longer than what I expect. The other direction is a cinch. 

I'm trying to shorten proofs as I'm reviewing for exams, and looking for shorter proofs has helped me remember stuff.

Comment: How about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-lebesgue-space)?

Comment: wow! That's perfect. I didn't see that though when I was searched this site. Thanks.