# $||f_n-f||_1 \to 0 $ iff $ \int| f_n|\ to \int|f| $ if $f_n \to f $ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Assume $f_n , f \in L^1 $ and almost every where we have $ f_n \to f$ then I want to show that $\int|f_n-f| \to 0$ iff $\int|f_n| \to \int|f|$

One side is abvious by trinagle inequality , for the other side I think I must use a theorem like Dominated covergence theorem but I can not reach a conclusion. Is there a modiffied form of dominated covergence theorem.

I need some hint , thanks.

Comment: You can argue as in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-lebesgue-space).

Comment: Use $|f_n - f| \leq |f_n| + |f|$. Your condition implies that $|f_n| + |f|$ is integrable.