# If $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ then $\sqrt f_n \rightarrow \sqrt f$ in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,m)$ be a measure space, $(f_n)_n,f \in L^1(m)$ all non-negative and $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$. Is it true that then $\sqrt{f_n} \rightarrow \sqrt f$ in $L^2$?

---

My try:
$$ \int (\sqrt{f_n} - \sqrt f)^2 = \int f_n + f - 2 \sqrt{f f_n} = \left(\int f_n - f \right) + 2\int f - \sqrt{ff_n}, $$
so I need just to prove that $\int f - \sqrt{ff_n} \rightarrow 0$.
But why does this holds?

Comment: Fatou's lemma should be useful here.

Comment: @DanielFischer But I don't have a.e. convergence...

Comment: You do for a subsequence.

Comment: _Every_ subsequence has a further subsequence that converges a.e. to $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose by contradiction $\sqrt{f_n} \not\rightarrow \sqrt f $ in $L^2$. Then, up to subsequences, we can suppose
$$ \int (\sqrt{f_n} - \sqrt{f})^2 \rightarrow C > 0,  $$
and $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e..
But in this situation by reverse Fatou we would have
$$ C= \lim \int (\sqrt{f_n} - \sqrt f)^2 \leq \int \lim (\sqrt{f_n} - \sqrt f)^2 = 0,$$
which is absurd.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reverse Fatou"? Fatou's Lemma yields exactly the reverse estimate of your estimate.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes of course, it's just a variation of Fatou's lemma: [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma)

Comment: For the reverse version, you need to know $f_n \leq g$ for all $n$ with $\int g d\mu <\infty$!

Comment: If $\|g_n - g\| \not \to 0$, then you do not necessarily have $\|g_n - g\| \to C$. Sometimes $\|g_n - g\|$ does not converge *at all*.

Comment: @PhoemueX Indeed consider the following inequality: $$ (\sqrt{f_n} - \sqrt f)^2 \leq 4(f_n + f), $$ which is a special case of the first inequality of the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-lebesgue-space)

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, but I am passing up to a subsequence

Comment: Passing to subsequences only helps if your sequences (or nets) are contained in some compact subset, which is not the case here.

Comment: @AlexM. But $[0,\infty]$ is compact, no?

Comment: Not to mention that your functions don't live in $[0,\infty]$ but in $L^1$, so you'd have to find a compact set therein.

Comment: @AlexM. If a non-negative sequence is bounded then it has a convergent subsequence. Otherwise it has a subsequence going to $\infty$. I don't understand what is your problem

Comment: What you say is true for sequences of numbers, not of functions (because $L^1$ is not locally compact). And you deal with sequences of functions, this is my problem (and yours).

Comment: @AlexM. Please read the text carefully. I am taking a subsequence of $h_n$ s.t. $\int h_n$, which is in $[0, \infty]$, converges to something.