# Almost sure convergence, convergence in mean

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Assume we have a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n \ge 1} \in L^p$, where $L^p$ is the space of all measurable functions with a finite $p$-th moment, which almost surely converge to $f \in L^p$. Further we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \| f_n\|_p =\|f\|_p
\end{align*}
This is sufficient to claim that $\|f_n - f \|_p \rightarrow 0$.

I have searched for a while on german and english sites for the proof of this statement, but wasn't succesful. It would be great, if someone could link me a source of the proof or write down his own.

Comment: See  [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp).