# $(f_n)$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ satisfying $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ a.e. and $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$, then $\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $1 < p < \infty$. If $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $L^p(\Omega)$ satisfying

1. $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ a.e.,
2. $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$,

then does it follow that $\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0$?

**Edit.** Here is my solution.

> For $A \subseteq \Omega$,\begin{align*}\|f_n - f\|_q & \le \|f_n - f\|_{u,\,\Omega - A}|\Omega - A|^{1\over q} + |A|^{{1\over q} - {1\over p}}\|f_n - f\|_p \\ & \le \|f_n - f\|_{u,\,\Omega - A}|\Omega - A|^{1\over q} + 2|A|^{{1\over q} - {1\over p}} \sup \|f_n\|_p \\ & \le \|f_n - f\|_{u,\,\Omega - A} |\Omega - A|^{1\over q} + 2M|A|^{{1\over q} - {1\over p}},\end{align*}where the second line follows by Fatou's lemma. By Egorov's theorem, we can choose $A$ arbitrarily small such that $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ on $\Omega - A$, so we are done.

I was wondering if anyone had any alternative solutions to this problem?

Comment: On a finite measure space, it certainly does. Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Try looking at the function $f_n+f-|f_n-f|$, and using Fatous lemma. It is the commonly given hint for this problem.

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson Or probably $|f_n|+|f|-|f_n-f|$; that gives the result for $p=1$.

Comment: @user In fact on a finite measure space it seems to me the argument I suspect you have in mind works (for $p>1$) assuming just that $||f_n||_p$ is bounded (and $||f||_p<\infty$). Then _if_ $||f_n||_p\to||f||_p$, one more epsilon extends that to the case of an infinite measure space. (Take $E$ of finite measure so $\int_E|f|^p>||f||_p^p-\epsilon$. Fatou's Lemma shows that the integral of $|f_n|^p$ over the complement of $E$ is less than $2\epsilon$ for large $n$.)

Comment: @user Never mind what I said - dropped a $p$.

Comment: There's a lot of that solution I don't follow... ?

Comment: Like, you seem to be assuming the space has finite measure. It looks like a proof that $||f_n-f||_q\to0$. You seem to be using the fact that the $L^q$ norm is dominated by the $L^p$ norm, which is not true unless $q\le p$. And you seem to be using the fact that $|A|^{1/q-1/p}\to0$ as $|A|\to0$< which is not true unless $q<p$. ???

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp).

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that
$$
0 \leq 2^p (|f_n|^p +|f|^p) -|f_n-f|^p.
$$
Hence by Fatou's lemma,
$$
2^{p+1} \int_\Omega |f|^p \leq \liminf_{n \to +\infty} \int_\Omega \left( 2^p (|f_n|^p +|f|^p) -|f_n-f|^p \right)  = 2^{p+1} \int_\Omega |f|^p - \limsup_{n \to +\infty} \int_\Omega |f_n-f|^p.
$$
Remark that this holds true also for $p=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Fatou's Lemma shows that $$\int_A|f|^p\le\liminf\int_A|f_n|^p$$for any $A$. Applying this to $A$ and to $X\setminus A$ and noting that $||f_n||_p\to||f||_p$ we see that in fact $$\int_A|f|^p=\lim\int_A|f_n|^p.$$

Say $\epsilon>0$. Choose a set $E$ of finite measure so $$\int_{X\setminus E}|f|^p<\epsilon.$$Choose $\delta>0$ so $\mu(A)<\delta$ implies $\int_A|f|^p<\epsilon$, and use Egoroff to get $F\subset E$ with $\mu(E\setminus F)<\delta$ and such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $F$. Now the thing at the start shows that $$\int_{X\setminus F}|f_n-f|^p<c\epsilon$$for large $n$, and $$\int_{F}|f_n-f|^p\to0.$$