# $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere and $\int |f_n| \to \int |f|$ implies $\int |f_n - f| \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $f_n$ and $f$ are integrable, $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, and $\int |f_n| \to \int |f|$. Does it necessarily follow that$$\int |f_n - f| \to 0?$$

Comment: Yes. You can use Fatou's Lemma to prove it.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f_k \to f$ a.e. and the $L^p$ norms converge, then $f_k \to f$ in $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

I can suppose , for ever $n=1,2,\cdots$
$$\|f_{n+1}-f_{n}\|_1\le 2^{-n} M$$ 
Set 
$$h_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f_k-f_{k-1}|=|f_1|+\sum_{k=2}^{n}|f_k-f_{k-1}|$$
therefore
$$\int_{\Omega}h_nd\mu=\|f_1\|_1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\|f_k-f_{k-1}\|_1$$
$$\int_{\Omega}h_nd\mu=\|f_1\|+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\|f_{k+1}-f_{k}\|_1$$
$$\int_{\Omega}h_nd\mu\le\|f_1\|+M\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^{-k}<M+\|f_1\|_1$$
we can say there is Integrable function $h$such that ${{h}_{n}}\uparrow h$ and
$$|f_n|=|\sum_{k=1}^{n}(f_k-f_{k-1})|\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}|f_k-f_{k-1}|=h_n\le h$$
Now you should show $f\le h$, then we have
$$|f_n-f|\le|f_n|+|f|\le 2h$$
Indeed 
$$\int_{\Omega}(f_n-f)d\mu\to 0$$