# $L^1([0,1])$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left\{ { f }_{ n } \right\}$  be a sequence of functions in ${ L }^{ 1 }\left( \left[ 0,1 \right]  \right) $ such that $\left\{ { f }_{ n } \right\}{ \longrightarrow  } f$ pointwise, almost everywhere.Show that $\left\{ { f }_{ n } \right\} \longrightarrow f$ in ${ L }^{ 1 }\left( \left[ 0,1 \right]  \right) $ if and only if $\left\{ { \left\| { f }_{ n } \right\|  }_{ 1 } \right\} \longrightarrow { \left\| f \right\|  }_{ 1 }$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us prove the non trivial part of the result.

Since $|f_n - f| \leq |f_n| + |f|$, it is enough to apply Fatou's Lemma to the sequence of non-negative functions $g_n := |f_n| + |f| - |f_n - f|$, obtaining
$$
\int_0^1 \liminf_n g_n = \int_0^1 2 |f| \leq
\liminf_n \int_0^1 g_n = \int_0^1 2|f| - \limsup_n \int_0^1 |f_n-f|.
$$ 
This gives
$$
\limsup_n \int_0^1 |f_n-f|\leq 0,
$$
i.e. $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is easy. For the other direction, you need a general version of Dominated Convergence Theorem saying the following: if $f_n,f$ are in $L^1$ and $g_n,g \in L^1$ are non-negative such that $|f_n| \le g_n$ and $|f| \le g$ a.e., $f_n \to f$ a.e., and $\int g_n \to \int g$ then $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$.

To prove this generalization, just adapt the proof of dominated convergence theorem.