# When almost surely convergence implies convergence in $L^{p}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm studying the types of convergence in probality and its relations and I have the following question:

What are the assumptions that together with almost surely convergence implies convergence in $L^p$?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at Vitali's convergence theorem for $L^p$.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51502/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f_k \to f$ a.e. and the $L^p$ norms converge, then $f_k \to f$ in $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp)