# Does convergence in every $L^p$ imply convergence in $L^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, lp-spaces

Consider a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ on a probability space $(X,\mu)$ such that

(i) $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ for every $p\in [1,\infty)$

(ii) $f,f_1,f_2,\cdots\in L^\infty$ and they are uniformly bounded in $L^\infty$ by $\Lambda\in [0,\infty)$, i.e. 
$$\|f\|_\infty,\|f_1\|_\infty,\|f_2\|_\infty,\cdots\le \Lambda.$$

Does then $f_n\to f$ in $L^\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t(x) = \max(0, 1-|x|)$, let
$f_n(x) = t(nx+n)$. Then $f_n \to 0$ for $p < \infty$ but $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Is the $+n$ necessary? If one uses [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp) I think one can get away with $f_n(x)=t(nx)$.

Comment: @0ßelö7: It is not necessary but the pointwise convergence is everywhere instead of ae.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. Thanks.