# Convergence in $L^2$ norm with $f_n \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

So, I know there is already a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp) which pretty much answers the following question:

> Given that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere and $\int |f_n|^2 \to \int |f|^2$, show that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ norm.

Of course, it is assumed that $f \in L^2$ and $\{f_n\} \subset L^2.$ However, my task now is to give a proof of the same result which makes use of the additional hypothesis that $f_n \geq 0$ for every $n$.

The only thing that I can immediately think of using is Fatou's Lemma. With the additional hypothesis, we can invoke Fatou to show that $$\int f \leq {\lim \inf} \int f_n$$

However, I'm currently unsure of how I may incorporate this result into a working proof. Would anyone happen to have any suggestions?

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp)

Comment: I already made reference to that post, but the proofs given there don't satisfy my requirements

Comment: Why do you want to use additional hypotheses? Are you leaving some of the old ones out?