# Is it true that a sequence $ f_n \to f $ of measurable functions is bounded by a norm of $ L^p $ then $ f_n $ converges to $f$ in $ L^p $?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Is it true that a sequence $ f_n \to f $ of measurable functions is bounded by a norm of $ L^p $ then $ f_n $ converges to f in $ L^p $?

Is this true? If so, prove, if not, a counter example.

I just know that $ || f_n ||_{p}  <M $ and that $\forall$ $\epsilon>0$  $\exists N_0 $ such that $\forall n>N_0  \Rightarrow |f_n -f |< \epsilon $

How to use this to show that

$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||f_n - f ||_{p} =0 $

Comment: It seems that in the linked question, we are asked to prove convergence in $L^1$, assuming that we work on a finite measurable space. This is not the same question, because we want convergence in $L^p$.

Answer (score 1):

If we furthermore assume that $\lVert f_n\rVert_p\to \lVert f\rVert_p$, [then it is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp).

Otherwise, we may be in trouble, for example $f_n(x)=n^{1/p}\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n)}(x)$ where we endow $(0,1)$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue measure.

Comment: A new picture? ${}$

Comment: @copper.hat Yes.