# If $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|$, then $\|f_n - f\| \to 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

I'm trying to prove this below result

> **Theorem:** Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Let $f_n, f \in \mathcal L_1 (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $\|f_n - f\| \to 0$.

Could you have a check if I correctly apply Fatou's lemma.

---

**My attempt:** We have
$$
\begin{align}
\limsup_n \int |f_n-f| &= - \liminf_n \int -|f_n-f|\\
&= - \liminf_n \int [|f_n| + |f|-|f_n-f|-(|f_n|+|f|)] \\
&\le -  \liminf_n \int (|f_n|+|f|-|f_n-f|) - \liminf_n \int-(|f_n| +|f|) \\
&= -  \liminf_n \int (|f_n|+|f|-|f_n-f|) + \limsup_n \int(|f_n|+|f|).
\end{align}
$$

- Because $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e., we get $|f_n|+|f|-|f_n-f| \to 2|f|$ $\mu$-a.e. By Fatou's lemma,
  $$
  \liminf_n \int (|f_n|+|f|-|f_n-f|) \ge  2\int |f| = 2 \|f\|_1.
  $$
- Because $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|_1$, we get
  $$
  \limsup_n \int (|f_n| + |f|) = \|f\|_1 + \limsup_n \|f_n\|_1= 2 \|f\|_1.
  $$

It follows that
$$
\lim_n \|f_n-f\|_1 \le \limsup_n \|f_n-f\|_1 = \limsup_n \int |f_n-f| \le 0.
$$

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp?noredirect=1&lq=1) can be generalized to $f, f_n \in\mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space, and $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $f_n, f \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0$.

*Proof:*

First, we have $|x-y|^p \le (|x|+|y|)^p \le (2 \max \{|x|, |y|\})^p = 2^p (\max \{|x|, |y|\})^p \le 2^p (|x|+|y|)^p$ for all $x,y \in E$. It follows that
$$
2^p (|f_n|^p + |f|^p) - |f_n-f|^p \ge 0 \quad \forall n.
$$

By Fatou's lemma, we get
$$
\int \liminf_n [2^p (|f_n|^p + |f|^p) - |f_n-f|^p] \le \liminf_n \int [2^p (|f_n|^p + |f|^p) - |f_n-f|^p].
$$

- Notice that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. implies $2^p (|f_n|^p + |f|^p) - |f_n-f|^p \to 2^{p+1} |f|^p$ $\mu$-a.e.
- If $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb R$ such that that $(a_n)$ is convergent in $\mathbb R$, then $\liminf (a_n+b_n) = \lim a_n + \liminf b_n$. Then
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \liminf_n \int [2^p (|f_n|^p + |f|^p) - |f_n-f|^p] &=\lim_n \int 2^p (|f_n|^p + |f|^p) +\liminf_n \int - |f_n-f|^p \\
  &=2^p \lim_n \int  (|f_n|^p + |f|^p) - \limsup_n \int |f_n-f|^p.
  \end{align}
  $$

It follows that
$$
\int 2^{p+1} |f|^p \le \int 2^{p+1} |f|^p - \limsup_n \int |f_n-f|^p.
$$

This completes the proof.