# A generalized version of dominated convergence theorem for Banach spaces

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to prove [this generalized version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72174/general-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem) of [dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space) for Banach space. Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space, and $p \in [1, \infty)$.

> **Theorem:** Let $f,g,f_n, g_n \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e., $g_n \to g$ $\mu$-a.e., $|f_n| \le |g_n|$ $\mu$-a.e., and $\|g_n\|_p \to \|g\|_p$. Then $\|f_n -f\|_p \to 0$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**My proof:** Because $p \ge 1$ and $|g_n| \ge |f_n|$ $\mu$-a.e., we have $|g_n|^p - |f_n|^p \ge 0$ $\mu$-a.e. By Fatou's lemma,
$$
\begin{align}
\int (|g|^p - |f|^p) &= \int \liminf_n (|g_n|^p - |f_n|^p) \\
&\le \liminf_n \int (|g_n|^p - |f_n|^p) \\
&= \lim_n \int |g_n|^p - \limsup_n \int |f_n|^p.
\end{align}
$$

Hence
$$
\limsup_n \int |f_n|^p \le \int |f|^p.
$$

We have $|g_n|^p+|f_n|^p \ge 0$ everywhere. By Fatou's lemma,
$$
\begin{align}
\int (|g|^p+|f|^p) &= \int \liminf_n (|g_n|^p+|f_n|^p) \\
&\le \liminf_n \int (|g_n|^p+|f_n|^p) \\
&= \lim_n \int |g_n|^p + \liminf_n \int |f_n|^p.
\end{align}
$$

Hence
$$
\liminf_n \int |f_n|^p \ge \int |f|^p.
$$

It follows that
$$
\liminf_n \int |f_n|^p \ge \int |f|^p \ge \limsup_n \int |f_n|^p.
$$

As such,
$$
\lim_n \|f_n\|_p = \|f\|_p.
$$

> [Lemma:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511720/if-f-n-to-f-mu-a-e-and-f-n-1-to-f-then-f-n-f-to-0/4511818#4511818) Let $f_n, f \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0$.

The claim then follows from above **Lemma**.