# Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure and $x_n \to x$. Is it true that $\mu (B(x_n, r)) \to \mu (B(x, r))$?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-measures, polish-spaces

Let $(E, d)$ be a Polish space and $\mu$ a finite Borel measure on $E$. Let $r>0$ and $x, x_n \in E$ such that $x_n \to x$.

> Is it true that$$
> \mu (B(x_n, r)) \to \mu (B(x, r))?
> $$

**My attempt:** Let $A_n := B(x_n, r)$ and $A := B(x, r)$. Then $1_{A_n} \to 1_A$ point-wise on $A$. If $y \notin A$ then $d(y, x) \ge r$. On the other hand, we only have $d(y, x_n) \ge d(y, x) - d(x, x_n) \ge r - d(x, x_n)$. As such, we are not sure if $1_{A_n} \to 1_A$ point-wise on $A^c$. Hence we can not apply DCT.

Comment: Let $E$ be the reals, $\mu=\delta_{1}, r=1$, and $x_n = {1 \over n}$. Then $\mu B(x_n,r) = 1$ for all $n$ but $\mu B(x,r) = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you post your counter-example as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: Please feel free to add the answer yourself!

Comment: @copper.hat I did so once and received some [backfire](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512442/is-this-variant-of-dominated-convergence-theorem-correct?noredirect=1#comment9475283_4512442)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E = \mathbb{R}$, $\mu = \delta_1$ (Dirac measure concentrated at $x=1$), $r=1$ and $x_n = {1 \over n}$ (with $x=0$, of course).

Then $\mu B(x_n, r) = 1$ for all $n$ but $\mu B(x,r) = 0$.