# Is it true that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\int f_n \to \int f$ imply $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|_1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space, and $p \in [1, \infty)$. In a previous thread, I proved that

> [Theorem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511720/if-f-n-to-f-mu-a-e-and-f-n-1-to-f-then-f-n-f-to-0/4511818#4511818) Let $f_n, f \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0$.

By **Theorem**, if $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e., then $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|_1 \iff \|f_n - f\|_1 \to 0$. As a corollary, if $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|_1$, then $\int f_n \to \int f$.

> Is it true that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\int f_n \to \int f$ imply $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|_1$? If not, please provide a counter-example.

Comment: $\chi_{[n,n+1]}-\chi_{[n+1,n+2]}$

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\Bbb R$, $f_n(x):=\frac xn\mathbf 1_{\{|x|\le n\}}$ tends pointwise to $f(x):=0$ as $n\to\infty$, with $\int f_n=0=\int f$. However $\|f_n\|_1=n$.