# A refinement of dominated convergence theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Let $p, q \in [1, \infty)$. Here we use [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Then we have

> [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4675031/a-version-of-dominated-convergence-theorem) Let $f,f_n \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ and  $g,g_n \in \mathcal L_q (X, \mu, E)$. We assume that
>
> - $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $g_n \to g$ a.e.,
> - $|f_n|^p \le |g_n|^q$ a.e. for all $n$, and $\|g_n\|_q \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \|g\|_q$.
>
> Then $\|f_n -f\|_p \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.

By below **Lemma 2**, the hypotheses of **Lemma 1** imply $\|g_n - g\|_q \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.

> [Lemma 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511720/if-f-n-to-f-mu-a-e-and-f-n-1-to-f-then-f-n-f-to-0/4511818#4511818) Let $f_n, f \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0$.

Now I would like to generalize **Lemma 1**, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f,f_n \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ and  $g,g_n \in \mathcal L_q (X, \mu, E)$. We assume that
>
> - **(H1)** each sub-sequence of $(f_n)$ has a further sub-sequence that converges a.e. to $f$,
> - **(H2)** $|f_n|^p \le |g_n|^q$ a.e. for all $n$, and $\|g_n - g\|_q \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.
>
> Then $\|f_n -f\|_p \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.

Could you have a check if I made some subtle mistakes that I could not recognize?

---

**My attempt** Let $\varphi$ be a sub-sequence of $\mathbb N$. Let $h_n := f_{\varphi (n)}$.

> [Urysohn principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/370951/1019043) A sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if and only if each sub-sequence of $(x_n)$ has a further sub-sequence which converges to $x$.

By **Urysohn principle**, it suffices to prove that $(h_n)$ has a sub-sequence that converges to $f$ in $L^p$. By **(H1)**, there is a sub-sequence $\psi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $h_{\psi (n)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f$ a.e. Let $l_n := g_{\varphi (n)}$. Clearly, $l_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} g$ in $L^q$, so there is a sub-sequence $\psi'$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $l_{\psi' (n)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} g$ a.e. WLOG, we assume $\psi = \psi'$. By **(H2)**, $(h_{\psi (n)}, l_{\psi(n)})_n$ satisfies the hypotheses of **Lemma 1**. Hence $h_{\psi (n)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f$ in $L^p$. This completes the proof.