# On the continuity of Nemytskii operators

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and for $r,p > 1$ consider
$$T: L^{pr}(\Omega) \to L^p(\Omega), \qquad T(u) = |u|^r.$$
I need to prove that $T$ is continous, but I don't know how to proceed. I have seem that this comes from the Nemytskii operators theory, but I couldn't find a reference with this proof.

Comment: Use `\qquad` for longer space.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: What is $(-1)^{\sqrt{2}}$? Is $x \mapsto x^{\sqrt{2}}$ continuous on the reals?

Comment: You need to write $|u|^r$. For continuity use dominated convergence.

Comment: I edited this, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u\in\mathbb L^{pr}(\Omega)$. We have to prove that if $(u_n)$ is a sequence converging in $L^{pr}(\Omega)$, then $\lVert T(u_n)-T(u)\rVert_{\mathbb L^p(\Omega)}\to 0$.
Note that it suffices to do it for $(u_n)$ satisfying $u_n\to u$ in $\mathbb L^{pr}(\Omega)$ and almost everywhere.

We use the following [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp): if $(v_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb L^q(\Omega)$ such that $v_n\to v$ almost everywhere and $\lVert v_n\rVert_{\mathbb L^q(\Omega)}\to \lVert v\rVert_{\mathbb L^q(\Omega)}$, then $\lVert v_n-v\rVert_{\lVert u_n\rVert_{\mathbb L^q(\Omega)}}\to 0$.

Applying this with $q=pr$, $v_n=\lvert u_n\rvert^r$ and $v=\lvert u\rvert^r$ gives the result.

Comment: Thank you Davide Giraudo for the reply.

Comment: @Thiago You are welcome.